# Nginx rewriting Rules

Tags: regex, nginx

I have the following url:

> mywebsite.com/template/product.html

and I want to rewrite it as

> mywebsite.com/product

```
location / {
  alias /var/www/web/;
  rewrite ^/(mywebsite.com/template/.*)\.html$ /$1 last;
}
```

Comment: Not sure I got the use case of your question in terms of http request. Do you want all requests `http://mywebsite.com/template/product.html` has to be redirected (302 or 301) to `http://mywebsite.com/product`? And again, why you added apache in the question tags?

Comment: I thought most apache users know about nginx. Yes, I want all requests to be redirected to ``http://mywebsite.com/product/``

Comment: Do you want handle the domain as a generic variable? Is this a kind of massive hosting?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you want to handle the domain as a generic variabile.

Anyway, if you setup a server conf for `mywebsite.com`, this configuration should fit your case.

```
server {
    error_log  logs/mywebsite.com.log  debug;

    server_name mywebsite.com;
    root /var/www/web/mywebsite.com;
    # this directive handle the redirects from old name.html to new format
    location /template/ {
       rewrite ^/template/([^.]+)\.html$ /$1 redirect;
    }
    # given new new url format this directive match the name and
    # read the file  
    location ~* ^/([^.]+)$ {
       try_files /template/$1.html /template/notfound.html;
    }
}
```

The regular expression you wrote did not match the product name. Now the group should fit your requirements. I have also modified the rewrite flag `last` in `redirect` because I suppose you want redirect a browser or a bot to the new urls.

Comment: Its working but its showing 404 Not found. What is the issue here?. No, not massive hosting. I want the same page to be seen in ``http://mywebsite.com/product/`` as in ``http://mywebsite.com/template/product.html``

Comment: The issue, is because the question is how to redirect the request from  `/template/name.html` to `/name`. There was no question about how read the html in the new url format. I suppose that you assumed the solution for new problem was expected. Anyway, I have updated my answer.